# How to assign first time key in python nested dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, dictionary, syntax, nested

I am getting error in else part how to update when key are not available my dict like given below

```
 product_data = {prod_id : {'purchase_price' : '','delivered_quantity' : ''} prod_id2 : {'purchase_price' : '','delivered_quantity' : ''}}


 product_data = {}
 if od_data["prod_id"] in product_data:
      product_data[od_data['prod_id']]['purchase_price'] += sum_of_purchase_price
      product_data[od_data['prod_id']]['delivered_quantity'] += mul_of_price
 else:
      product_data[od_data['prod_id']]['delivered_quantity'] = od_data["prod_id"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand what you are trying to achieve but you kinda went out of your way to not let yourself achieve it. You emptied your dictionary product_data just before checking od_data["prod_id"] is in product_data or not(which is empty because of your second line).